# Multiple Spring 3.2 scheduled tasks won't run in parallel

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I have two scheduled tasks that I want to run in parallel. These two tasks execute a Spring Batch job. One every 15 seconds and the other ever 3 seconds. The problem is one will be running and the other is blocked until it finishes.

I can't seem to find a similar question or example anywhere. Any ideas? Thanks, /w

Here's a bit of my configuration. I'm using spring-task-3.2 and spring-batch-2.2 with Spring 3.2.

This batch job is ran by the `mappingRunScheduler`. The other task `runScheduler` is very similar and no beans are shared.

```
<job id="mappingJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="mappingStep1" next="mappingStep2">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="mappingItemReader" 
                    processor="mappingItemProcessor" 
                    writer="mappingItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>        
    <step id="mappingStep2">
        <tasklet ref="mappingTasklet" />
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="mappingTasklet" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingTasklet" 
        scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mappingLister" />
</bean>

<bean id="mappingItemWriter" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingItemWriter" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="mappingLister" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingLister" 
        scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="liveRepositoryService" />
</bean>

<bean id="mappingItemProcessor" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingItemProcessor" 
        scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="liveRepositoryService" />
</bean> 

<bean id="mappingItemReader" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingItemReader" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>#{mappingLister.getModifiedList()}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mappingRunScheduler" 
        class="com.example.repository.batch.MappingRunScheduler" />

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" 
            method="run" cron="*/15 * * * * *" />
    <task:scheduled ref="mappingRunScheduler" 
            method="run" cron="*/3 * * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

The `MappingRunScheduler` - runs the batch job.

```
@Service(value = "mappingRunScheduler")
@Component
public class MappingRunScheduler {

    public MappingRunScheduler() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String uuid = new Date().toString() + "-" 
                    + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("uuid", uuid)
                    .addString("job", "mapper").toJobParameters();
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException 
                | JobRestartException 
                | JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would start with the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) - specifically the heading _25.4.3 The 'scheduled-tasks' element_. It describes now to specify a custom scheduler. The default scheduler has only one thread in its thread pool - described under the _25.4.1 The 'scheduler' element_ heading.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider. I'm looking into `<task:scheduler />`. Overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

@BoristheSpider pointed me in the right direction. Needed to configure my tasks like this. Will need to tune the pool size, but this allows the jobs to run in parrallel.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="batchScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" 
            method="run" cron="*/15 * * * * *" />
    <task:scheduled ref="mappingRunScheduler" 
            method="run" cron="*/3 * * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduler id="batchScheduler" pool-size="100" />
```

Comment: I certainly wouldn't set it to 100. Anything more than 10 is usually a mistake. In your case 2 will work...

Comment: Oh okay, I'll bump that down. Wasn't sure about that part.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should specify a `TaskExecutor` implementation in your `JobLauncher` to allow it to launch jobs asynchronously, here is a configuration example from `Spring Batch Admin` Context :

```
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="jobLauncherTaskExecutor" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="jobLauncherTaskExecutor" pool-size="6" rejection-policy="ABORT" />
```