# spring scheduler not running if a job not finished

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to make a lib for my spring applications. It has a scheduled job, it is autoconfigured and working as included Maven dependency in most cases.

I have a webapp which basically just flood requests to other webapps (some basic load-testing and fail-detection). The requester implementation is fully async (it has a manually configured async executor too). The web app has a periodic job too, but it doesn't finish reliably its job within the 2 minutes timeframe. It still fine. BUT.

When I started to use my firstly described lib on the secondly described server the lib starts working unreliable. It's not triggered every 2 minutes anymore. I don't have enough spring knowledge to find out why.

My best bet is the servers flood method starts a lot of async tasks, and the scheduler start these tasks, too and these requests are going to the same message queue.

Is there any method to separate my libs scheduled tasks from other servers scheduled tasks and make them running reliable every 2 minutes?

Comment: Could you please share code as to how you have configured your task execution and scheduler related configuration

You might want to take a look into this, if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21409068/3838328

Comment: I'm far from my code now, but its a springboot app. I think it would be enought if I can define in my lib a separated Executor. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207023/multiple-threadpooltaskexecuters-spring-java-config) will be solve my problem, but I'm not sure and can't try it right now, maybe tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my research is interesting... It seems to be, only configuring an async executor will force the scheduler to use that too. But if you implements schedulerConfigurer too, you will get another thread pool dedicated to scheduled tasks only.

So my implementation is something like this for separate the 2 threadpool.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
public class WebService extends AsyncConfigurerSupport implements SchedulingConfigurer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "web-server");
    SpringApplication.run(WebService.class, args);
}
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("tester-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown", name = "scheduledExecutor")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="scheduledExecutor")
Executor scheduledExecutor;

@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(scheduledExecutor);
}
```

Still not clear enough if I could create a separated thread-pool for my lib or not, but its good enough for now.